# Why do we need to use $(this) in a .each() function?

Tags: jquery

I am new to programming and am finding this code a bit confusing. I know that the line that is selecting all input fields with the type text, loops through each field.

So why it using `$(this)` because it already made a selection, which was all input fields with the type text.

```
$('#combine').click(function() {
    var combined_text = "";
    $('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
        combined_text += $(this).val() + ' ';
    });
    alert(combined_text);
});
```

Comment: `each()` returns an array of elements that match the selector, but the function within the parenthesis runs on each of them individually, so you need `this` to specify each of the elements.  Please visit the jquery site and read the documentation - this is all covered very well.

Comment: @Archer Exactly.You should add this is an answer :)

Answer (score 4):

[From docs directly](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

> The .each() method is designed to make DOM looping constructs concise and less error-prone. When called it iterates over the DOM elements that are part of the jQuery object. Each time the callback runs, it is passed the current loop iteration, beginning from 0. More importantly, the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, **so the keyword this refers to the element.**

And

> To access a jQuery object instead of the regular DOM element, use $(this).

[Some good explanation here](http://css-plus.com/2011/09/master-the-jquery-for-each-loop/)

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `each()` callback function, `this` refers to the dom element, not to a jQuery wrapped element.

So when you need to access jQuery methods, you need to wrap it using `$(this)`.

Ex

if you say `this.value`, it will give the value of the element inside the loop

Answer (score 1):

Using the `.each` function starts a loop through the matched elements.

`$(this)`, refers to the current element, belonging to the group of matched elements!

Answer (score 0):

`each` is `jQuery loop function`, So, inside `each` every matching element will consider individual object for jQuery. If you use `JavaScript` then you can use `this.value` but here you are playing with `jQuery` so you have to follow `jQuery rules.` Because, **`val`** is `jQuery function` to get current `object value` hence you have to use `$(this)`. Because **`$`** will change `this` to a `jQuery Object`. :)

**`in JavaScript we can get object value by 'this.value();' in loop`**

**`in jQuery we can use above code but right baby is '$(this).val();'`**

Answer (score -1):

Using $(this) to get your $('input[type="text"]') ==> all input text in your paragraph